# printJobCompleted on PrintJobEvents is not Working in java

Tags: java, printing

I am currently working with printing pdf documents to a physical printer. The printing operation is successful but not with the execution of the printJobCompleted on PrintJobEvents. I want to know why it is not working while the printDataTransferCompleted and the printJobNoMoreEvents works?

This is my code:

```
    PdfBook pdfBook = new PdfBook(decodePdf, printingDevice, attributeSet);
    SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(pdfBook, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, null);
    DocPrintJob printJob = printingDevice.createPrintJob();
    //ADD A LISTENER
   printJob.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Data transfer is complete");
        String itwillout = "Destined";
        System.out.println(itwillout);
    }
        @Override
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Data transfer is complete");
        String verify = "This means that the print job is complete!";
        System.out.println(verify);
        variablez = "abc";
    }
        @Override
        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent event) {
        System.out.println("No more events will be received");
    }
    });
 try {
      printJob.print(doc, attributeSet);


    } catch (PrintException e) {
        LogWriter.writeLog("Exception " + e + " printing");
    }

    decodePdf.closePdfFile();  

//I placed this to verify if the job is completed

    while(variablez != "abc"){
        System.out.println("The printer is not yet finished in printing!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(7000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
       if (variablez == "abc"){
                    break;
                }
    }
    if (done == true){
    System.out.println("Exiting printing process"); 

}
```

Is it the code above the problem, or is it the printer that I'm using? Or I missed something on the code above.

My Goal: The while loop will continuously run until it meet a certain condition. If the variablez is equal to the String "abc" then it will get out of the loop and execute the remaining commands or codes.

Note: I declared String variablez = null; at the uppermost portion of the class

Comment: for me only `printDataTransferCompleted` and `printJobNoMoreEvents` called

Comment: Same, Cannot get any other events to come through. Also for some reason each one gets called twice in a row...  Still looking for an answer to this problem.